# How can I keep previous state and add a new state to the previous state in Redux reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux

The below is one of my reducers. In the function `applySetRandomImages`, I want to access previous state of `randomImages` to add a new state of `randomImages` with the previous state.

How can I do that? does the reducer function in Redux provides some call back function for that? or should I implement that on my own?

```
// ACTIONS
const SET_RANDOM_IMAGES = "SET_RANDOM_IMAGES";

// ACTION CREATORS
function setRandomImages(randomImages) {
  return {
    type: SET_RANDOM_IMAGES,
    randomImages
  };
}

// API ACTIONS
function getRandomImages(page) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    fetch(`/boutiques/random-images/?page=${page}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(setRandomImages(json.results)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
}

// INITIAL STATE
const initialState = {};

// REDUCER
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_RANDOM_IMAGES:
      return applySetRandomImages(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// REDUCER FUNCTIONS
function applySetRandomImages(state, action) {
  const { randomImages } = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    randomImages    <--- I need to merge the randomImages with a new state of randomImages
  };
}

// EXPORTS
const actionCreators = {
  getRandomImages,
};
export { actionCreators };

// DEFAULT REDUCER EXPORTS
export default reducer;
```

Comment: So, you have `randomImages` in your state and you want to merge it with the ones come with your action? Is it an array or an object?

Comment: Yes, I want to merge the upcoming one with the existing one. It's array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge `randomImages` by spreading the old state and the new one into a new array:

```
function applySetRandomImages(state, action) {
  const { randomImages } = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    randomImages: [...state.randomImages, ...randomImages],
  };
}
```

Comment: that's what I tried, but when I console.log it, it returns undefined

Comment: Didn't check if `randomImages` exists at the very beginning!. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I fixed a mistake in my answer. I forgot to spread the new `randomImages`.

Answer (score 1):

Separate `actions`, `reducers` and `types` into their own folders.

**types/index.js**

```
export const SET_RANDOM_IMAGES = "SET_RANDOM_IMAGES";
```

**actions/imageActions.js**

```
import * as types from '../types';

export const getRandomImages = page => dispatch => (
  fetch(`/boutiques/random-images/?page=${page}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch({ type: types.SET_RANDOM_IMAGES, payload: json.results })))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
)
```

From within a component, you will `connect` to redux state (`state.images` or `state.images.collection`) and `dispatch` the `action` (`getRandomImages`):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getRandomImages } from '../actions/imageActions';

class Example extends Component {

   componentDidMount = () => this.props.getRandomImages(); // dispatches action creator

   render = () => (
       <div>
         { /* 
             The props below are redux state passed into 
             the component via the connect function
         */ }
         {this.props.images.map(image => (
           <img src={image.src} alt="image.name" />
         ))}
         {this.props.collection.map(image => (
           <img src={image.src} alt="image.name" />
         ))}
       </div>
   )
}

export default connect(state => ({ 
  images: state.images, // pulled from redux state (state.images => this.props.images)
  collection: state.images.collection // pulled from redux state (state.images.collection => this.props.images.collection)
}), { getRandomImages})(Example)
```

It will then trigger the `AJAX` request, then return a `type` and `payload` to your `reducer`:

**reducers/index.js**

```
import * as types from '../types'

// overwrite images for each successful fetch request
const imageReducer(state={}, {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    // spread out any previous state, then spread out the payload (json.results)
    case types.SET_RANDOM_IMAGES: return { ...state, ...payload }
    default: return state;
  }
}

// or append images on each successful fetch request...
const imageReducer(state={}, {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    case types.SET_RANDOM_IMAGES: 
      return { 
        ...state,  // spread out any previous state
        collection: [ 
          ...state.collection, //  then spread out any previous "collection" state, 
          ...payload // then spread/append the payload (json.results) 
        ]
      }
    default: return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  images: imageReducer
});
```

The reducer will then spread out any previous `imageReducer` state, then append the `res.results` to it via `payload`. Now it exists in redux as `state.images` or `state.images.collection`. This is then pulled from redux state and into the component above as `this.props.images` or `this.props.images.collection`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access previous state of randomImages to add a new state of randomImages with the previous state

```
return {
    ...state,
    ...randomImages
};
```

If previous `state` was:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
```

And `randomImages` is:

```
{
    d: 4,
    e: 5
}
```

Then the returned new state will be

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
}
```